# Nextjs website crashes/freezes on IOS device

Tags: next.js, mobile-safari, vercel, framer-motion

Hi I have developed a website using Nextjs and Framer Motion and deployed it to Vercel: https://www.launchit.be/

On the desktop, everything works fine, but when I load the page from my mobile device (iPhone), the site seems to crash/freeze when I scroll down... Does anyone know why this happens and how to prevent it?

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

EDIT: Seems to be a Safari-specific bug.
EDIT: The site also crashes on the Chrome app on Iphone.

Answer (score 1):

Works fine on my iPhone 13 (iOS 16.6) in Chrome.

Edit: Tested in Safari and saw the bug. Looks like a Safari-specific bug and not an iOS-specific.

Answer (score -1):

I found the issue is related to this file
`https://pgu2022.vercel.app/_next/static/css/71c9678f5295262f.css`

If you remove the above stylesheet, the page renders fine and does not crash.

Comment: Where did you find this file?

Comment: That link is not related to my website.

Comment: Generally it occurs due to CSS issues, safari can sometimes crash over simple stuff such as transform: scale(0.5, -0.05); filter: brightness(0.2) blur(50px); declaration

My suggestion would be to check and debug the css, it most probably will be the above case itself

Comment: I just tried the website via the Chrome app on my phone, this also crashes..